# Silverlight and UserControls registered as COM

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls

I have a .NET user control registered as COM. I use regasm to register the control and can then use it in a web page.

I have hear that Silverlight 4 supports COM, is that true ? would I be able to use my UserControl in a silverlight application ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Silverlight 4 can work with COM clients](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx#com), but only in a trusted, Out Of Browser application.